# IE8 Garbles Shortcut

Tags: windows

A simple AutoHotKey shortcut to enter my email address worked perfectly with my XP system using Internet Explorer 8.0 (and previous) for several years mostly on the web and occasionally in Office 2010.
A month+ ago the shortcut started dropping seemingly random characters (or numeralsor the period or @) from the entered data, typically three characters but different each time.  At a C: promptor in Word the shortcut still works perfectly.
I suspect an anto-update to IE caused the problem but the question posted on the MS IE site yielded nothing useful.
Suggestions on how to make the shortcut again work on the web will be appreciated.
Thank you.

BobK

Answer (score 0):

Bob, Have you tried running AutoHotKey with admin rights. This seems to be a recurring problem in Windows 8.